# Android Notification smallIcon not displaying properly

Tags: android, notifications, icons

So I've been working with Android Notifications and after setting a large image, I found out that my small image is actually not displaying properly.

As you can see on the following screenshot of the lockscreen, the background of the small icon is transparent. I want to set a specific colour there, just like the one Outlook.com is using:

[image: a]

Another example where the small icon shows next to the large one (please take notice of the small icon which is actually displaying, but not really noticable because there is just no background):

[image: b]

I've been thinking about changing the small icon to include the background colour, but obviously the colour would also be shown in the statusbar and that's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `setColor()` with `NotificationCompat.Builder` to set the accent color, which should be used by the colored circle behind the icon.

Comment: It worked! I tried 'setColor()' on the Builder before and it didn't work then. Apparently I did something wrong testing it. Thank man!

Comment: It does not work for me... The background stays transparent even if I call `setColor(Color.BLUE)`. When I log the notification, I can see that the color is set but still, the background is transparent...
`Notification(pri=0 contentView=foo.bar.testappsdk/0x1090078 vibrate=[0,250,250,250,250] sound=content://settings/system/notification_sound defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0xff0000ff groupKey=foo.bar.testappsdk.MainActivity vis=PRIVATE)`

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I needed to set the SDK version to 21